# How do you show that an absolute value is non-archimedean if $\sup\{|n|: n \text{ is an integer}\}= C<\infty$ and how to show that $C=1$?

Tags: analysis, number-theory, absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

I've been trying to work this out but I've been stuck and can't seem to see how to work through a proof of this. It's part of a lemma I'm trying to study in p-adic analysis but the textbook doesn't give a proof for me to follow.

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us the textbook you're following.

Comment: I'm using P-adic numbers by Gouvea 3rd edition. He gives a problem after a lemma but doesn't provide a proof. It's in the second chapter

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956792/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1748861/96384.

Comment: Please do not change the title to something that makes the question incomprehensible. I have reverted that.

Comment: Do the close voters understand the question (and the answer)??

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is an integral domain with an absolute value such that $\sup_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} |n|<\infty$.

With $|n|$ I mean $|n 1_R|$.

If $|n|> 1$ then $\lim_{k\to \infty} |n^k| = \infty$. So $\sup_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} |n|<\infty$ implies $\sup_{n\in \Bbb{Z}} |n|\le 1$.

Assume that for some $a,b\in R, |a+b|>|a|\ge |b|$. Then
$$|(a+b)^k|\le \sum_{m=0}^k | {k \choose m}a^m b^{k-m}|
\le (k+1) |a|^k$$
But $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{|a+b|^k}{(k+1)|a|^k}= \infty$ so this is a contradiction.

Therefore $\forall a,b\in R, |a+b|\le \max(|a|,|b|)$ ie. $|.|$ is non-archimedian.